# How to start video recording in Android TV (development)

Tags: stream, recording, android-tv

I would like to implement video recording in Android TV, or at least a button that fires the recording event, I added the gradle dependency, but I could not find any RecordAction or RecordButton, only MultiAction, FastForwardAction etc.

What I would need is a button where the user clicks/presses and the current time of the current streamed media would be saved.

Answer (score 1):

You may follow this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/content-recording.html). To tell the system that your TV input service supports recording, set the `android:canRecord` attribute in your service metadata XML file to `true`:

```
<tv-input xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:canRecord="true"
  android:setupActivity="com.example.sampletvinput.SampleTvInputSetupActivity" />
```

Alternatively, you can indicate recording support in your code using these steps:

1. In your TV input service [`onCreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onCreate()) method, create a new [`TvInputInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.html) object using the [`TvInputInfo.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.Builder.html) class.
2. When creating the new [`TvInputInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.html) object, call [`setCanRecord(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.Builder.html#setCanRecord(boolean)) before calling [`build()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.Builder.html#build()) to indicate your service supports recording.
3. Register your [`TvInputInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputInfo.html) object with the system by calling [`TvInputManager.updateTvInputInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputManager.html#updateTvInputInfo(android.media.tv.TvInputInfo)).

Regarding button where the user clicks/presses, unfortunately I can't find any samples about it. According to the same reference above, the system will invoke the [`RecordingSession.onStartRecording()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputService.RecordingSession.html#onStartRecording(android.net.Uri)) callback when the system calls [`RecordingSession.onTune()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/tv/TvInputService.RecordingSession.html#onTune(android.net.Uri)). Then your app must start recording immediately.

Comment: Yes I found the same, so I guess I have to manually call onTune somehow, and implement an extra button.